# jpeg image compression : byte order issue

Tags: jpeg, image-compression

If jpeg image is little-endian, then what difference will come in its format? I have two types of images in jpeg - one is little-endian and another one is big-endian using jpegsnoop application, but in hex-format, I found everything the same, no change at all. But while compressing it I'm getting the issue on little-endian jpeg image.

please look at app marker of both image (0xFFE1)

Image 1 (which having compression error)

```
JPEGsnoop 1.7.3 by Calvin Hass
  http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/
  -------------------------------------

  Filename: [D:\New folder\PICT0001.JPG]
  Filesize: [2700154] Bytes

Start Offset: 0x00000000
*** Marker: SOI (xFFD8) ***
  OFFSET: 0x00000000

*** Marker: APP1 (xFFE1) ***
  OFFSET: 0x00000002
  Length          = 15358
  Identifier      = [Exif]
  Identifier TIFF = 0x[49492A00 08020000]

  ***Endian          = Intel (little)***

TAG Mark x002A  = 0x002A




/***********************************************************/
**image 2** (ok image )

JPEGsnoop 1.7.3 by Calvin Hass
  http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/
  -------------------------------------

  Filename: [D:\Trailing_Project\OBSERVATION\12-09-2017\original jpeg\MFDC0058.JPG]
  Filesize: [1398695] Bytes

Start Offset: 0x00000000
*** Marker: SOI (xFFD8) ***
  OFFSET: 0x00000000


    *** Marker: APP1 (xFFE1) ***
      OFFSET: 0x00000002
      Length          = 3556
      Identifier      = [Exif]
      Identifier TIFF = 0x[4D4D002A 00000008]

      ***Endian          = Motorola (big)***

      TAG Mark x002A  = 0x002A
```

Comment: Either you have a valid jpeg or you do not. Endianness for jpeg is defined in the standard!

Comment: You say that both files appear identical when looking at them in hexadecimal format, but that a utility called jpegsnoop disagrees?  What exactly do you mean: _I  found everything the same_ with regards to the two files.  It is difficult to believe that if the files are _the same_, that there would be any difference in how they appear, or are compressed.

Comment: That's clearly not about the C language or image-processing. Don't spam tags! Not even sure if this counts as programming quetion at all. It is about a data-format which is well documented.

Answer (score 1):

All integers in JPEG are BIG ENDIAN (Network order). If you have little endian integers it is not JPEG.

Comment: I am adding two jpeg starting details of image  .please lookover it, where it showing little endian and big endian, shown by "jpegsnoop" application.Note:-i have not added full details of the image.